# Google Speech Recognition not working

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So i recently decided to again redo the infrastructure of my Jarvis AI. Now i'm using a mix of the code (Google and Microsoft). The Google part of the code will not trigger for some reason and display any words or text when spoken into microphone.

```
public const int DEFAULT_BIT_RATE = 8000;
public const string DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en-US";
static string client = "Jarvis";
public class SpeechInputResult
{
        static public string ID;
        public int status;

        public class Hypothesis
        {
            public string utterance;
            public double confidence = -1.0d;//-1 = No Value
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "'" +utterance + "'" + ((confidence == -1) ? "" : "@" + confidence);
            }
            public List<Hypothesis> hypotheses = new List<Hypothesis>();

            public Hypothesis getBestHypothesis()
            {
                if (hypotheses.Count() <=0)
                    return null;
                Hypothesis H = hypotheses[0];
                foreach (Hypothesis h in hypotheses)
                {
                    if (h.confidence>=H.confidence)
                    {
                        H = h;
                    }
                    return H;
                }
                return null;
            }
            public string json_men = "";
            public void FromJSON(String JSON)
            {
                json_men = JSON;
                JSON = JSON.Replace("\n","").Trim();
                Match M;

                //status
                M = new Regex("\\\"status\\\"\\:([0-9]*),", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(JSON);

                //ID
                M = new Regex ("\\\"id\\\"\\:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(JSON);
                ID = M.Groups[1].Value;

                //Hypotheses
                int l1 = JSON.IndexOf("hypotheses");
                    l1 = JSON.IndexOf("[",l1);
                int r1 = JSON.LastIndexOf("]");
                string JSON2 = JSON.Substring(l1, r1-l1+1);

                MatchCollection m2 = new Regex("{([^\\}]*)}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(JSON2);
                foreach (Match g in m2)
                {
                    string s = g.Value;
                    SpeechInputResult.Hypothesis h = new SpeechInputResult.Hypothesis();

                    M = new Regex("\\\"utterance\\\"\\:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(s);
                    h.utterance  = M.Groups[1].Value;

                    M = new Regex("\\\"confidence\\\"\\:([0-9\\.]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(s);
                    string confidence = M.Groups[1].Value;
                    confidence = confidence.Replace(".", ",");
                    if (confidence != "")
                    {
                        h.confidence = float.Parse(confidence);
                    }
                    hypotheses.Add(h);
                }
            }
        }
        public static SpeechInputResult ProcessFlacFile(string FlacFileName, int BIT_RATE = DEFAULT_BIT_RATE, string language = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, uint maxresults = 1)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1" + "&client=" + client + "&lang=" + language + "&maxresults=" + maxresults + "&pfilter=0");
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(FlacFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=8000";
            //bitrate must = .flac file
            request.UserAgent = client;
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FlacFileName);
            long numbytes = fInfo.Length;
            byte[] data = null;
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(FlacFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                data = new byte[fstream.Length];
            fStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fStream.Length));
            fStream.Close();
            using (Stream wrStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                wrStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                dynamic resp = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (resp != null)
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp);
                    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    //resp.Close();
                    //resp.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hi"+ee);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The code here is all from [this website](https://code.google.com/p/voice-recognition-and-synthesis-csharp-google-sapi/source/browse/+voice-recognition-and-synthesis-csharp-google-sapi+--username+ranma1988@gmail.com/CLASSES/Google_SpeechAPI.cs?r=1).

After getting it to no errors it still doesn't return or do anything, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing JSON with regular expressions will usually cause you problems.  Consider using a library like JSON.NET to parse the string into an object instead.